# I am trying to search up to the right diagonally in my multidimensional array in java. Why am I getting index out of bounds error?

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to search up to the right diagonally in my multidimensional array of characters in java. I added in an if statement to make sure it stays within the bounds of the array, but I am getting an index out of bounds error. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
        // search diagonal up to right
    if ((row - 1 >=0) && (col + 1 <= board[col].length)) {
        boolean foundWord = true;

        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row - 1][col + 1]) {
                foundWord = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(foundWord) {
            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
        }
    } // end search diagonal up to right
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is my solution.

This line:

```
if ((row - 1 >=0) && (col + 1 <= board[col].length)) {
```

Was changed to this:

```
if((row - word.length() <= 0) && (col + word.length() <= board[row].length)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Array numeration starts from 0, so here `col + 1 <= board[col].length` you should use `board[col].length-1`

Comment: I'm still getting index out of bounds.

Comment: Could you specify, on which line of code do you get it? It may be not that line, but word.length() in inner loop

Comment: It says i'm getting it on this line: if ((row - 1 >=0) && (col + 1 <= board[col].length)) {

Comment: if you changed code to 'board[col].length - 1', then it must be 'board[col]' causing that mistake. Try looking at that

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are zero-based, that is their indexes start from zero and therefore the highest index is `length - 1`.

Change the comparison operator from `<=` to `<`, so it doesn't reach `length`:

```
if ((row - 1 >=0) && (col + 1 = board[col].length)) {
//                             ^---- change here
```

Comment: I'm still getting index out of bounds.